# Setting variables to rooms in node.js + socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building a webchat using node.js and socket.io; when a webuser connects to the chat i create a room for him and i would like to set variables to the room, so that iterating on it i get the values for every single user.

Is there a way to set variables for a room or do i need to use "external" tools like arrays or db?

Answer (score 2):

A more vanilla way is to simply store your variables in `io.sockets.adapter.rooms`

It is an object with a list of the current rooms.

To store a variable to the room, simply do:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms['MY_AWESOME_ROOM'].myAwesomeVariable = 'state'
```

Comment: `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` seems to be a Map so `rooms['MY_AWESOME_ROOM']` does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I created a module just for this purpose: https://www.npmjs.org/package/roomdata

#### How it works:

It creates a rooms variable which is just a object holding nothing, When a user joins a room it checks if rooms[roomname] exists. If it does not exists rooms[roomname] will be created and now you can apply variables to it. This module just makes it easier to do this.